# Plotting two pandas dataframe columns against each other in multiindex

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plot

Let's say, we have a pandas DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1,2,3,4,5],[3,4,5,6,7]]).T, columns=['a','b'])

print(df)
```

which gives me:

```
   a  b
0  1  3
1  2  4
2  3  5
3  4  6
4  5  7
```

if I try to plot column 'a' on column 'b', I can very simply do:

```
df.plot(x='a', y='b')
plt.show()
```

and so I do get my graph.

But if I have a DataFrame with a MultiIndex on the Columns, then I have a problem:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1,2,3,4,5],[3,4,5,6,7]]).T, columns=[['a','b'],['y','w']])

print(df)
```

which gives me:

```
   a  b
   y  w
0  1  3
1  2  4
2  3  5
3  4  6
4  5  7
```

so if I do now:

```
df.plot(x=['a','y'], y=['b','w'])
plt.show()
```

I get the following error:

```
File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 117, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 139, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1265, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1273, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'y'
```

Am I doing anything wrong?

Or is pandas not able to plot when using a MultiIndex?

Comment: You can. You just need to set the index before plotting. Try `df.set_index(('a', 'y')).plot()`.

Comment: Thanks, this work, but is just a workaround. I expect the function plot(x=['a','y'], y=['b','w'])  to work both with single and with multiple column index.

Comment: Well, sorry, but it won't.

Comment: No, I see it won't, but I think then pandas should work on it for code coherency.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
df.set_index(('a','y')).plot()
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Aha, didn't see your answer when I posted my comment.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, thank you! Congratulations! You are [legendary] now! ;-)

Comment: Thank you so much! Couldn't have done it without you guys :-)

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Congratulations !! lengendary achieved

Comment: @Wen Thanks, couldn't have done it without you guys' help!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a more straight forward way to do it:

```
df.plot(x=('a','y'), y=('b','w'))
```